# Parse expression on brackets or whitespace - Python

Tags: python, regex

I have the following string:

```
'unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     18135    /run/user/1000/systemd/private'
```

so I'm trying to parse it using Python's `re` module:

```
import re
text = 'unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     18135    /run/user/1000/systemd/private'
>>> re.split(r'\s+[\[?\s+\]]', text)
['unix', '2', ' ACC', '', 'STREAM', 'LISTENING', '18135', '/run/user/1000/systemd/private']
```

while the expected expression would be:

```
['unix', '2', '[ ACC ]', 'STREAM', 'LISTENING', '18135', '/run/user/1000/systemd/private']
```

Also, text could be with or without `[]`, for example:

```
tcp4       0      0  localhost.53019        localhost.53920        ESTABLISHED
```

What am I missing on my regex expression?

Comment: Are you asking what could be improved? Or is the regex expression not working for your needs?

Comment: `re.split("\s{2,}",text)`, if I understand what you're asking.

Comment: I highly suggest this resource for writing regular expressions: http://regexr.com/

Answer (score 0):

You include brackets (`\[` and `\]`) in the expression for the delimiter, so they won't appear in the items.